# Javascript if/else with Multiple Conditional Based off of CSS Property and window width Not functional

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create an alert system that 'pushes' the nav and sticky elements down when an alert is displayed and returns them to the top of the screen when the alert is closed. Ideally, the alert display will be delayed a bit. Right now the system works well IF the browser window is not resized. I'm not sure if it's a syntax error in my conditional or what. Or maybe there is a better way to use .resize. Here is my script. When the alert is closed at windowSize >= 950 and then the browser is made smaller the .top-bar lingers. When the alert is close at windowSize <= 950 and made larger, the .top-bar does not display.

I'm familiar with media queries, should I be using .onclick (deleting the alert) to add/remove CSS classes?

I've made a rough pen of what I've got so far.

https://codepen.io/drewalth/pen/ypPxBy

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function slideNav() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize <= 950) {
      $('.membershipAlert').css("top", "0px");
      $('.top-bar').css("top", "-35px");
      $('header').css("top", "35px");
      $('.isSticky').css({
        "top": "137px",
        "position": "relative"
      });
      $('.sticky-box').css({
        "top": "137px",
        "position": "relative"
      });
    } else if (windowSize >= 950) {
      $('.membershipAlert').css("top", "0px");
      $('.top-bar').css("top", "35px");
      $('header').css("top", "70px");
      $('.isSticky').css({
        "top": "137px",
        "position": "sticky"
      });
      $('.sticky-box').css({
        "top": "137px",
        "position": "sticky"
      });
    }

  }

  function membershipClose() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize <= 950) {
      $('.membershipClose').click(function() {
        $('.membershipAlert').css("top", "-70px");
        $('.top-bar').css("top", "-35px");
        $('header').css("top", "0px");
        $('#cd-lateral-nav').css("top", "0px");

      });

    } else if (windowSize >= 950) {
      $('.membershipClose').click(function() {
        $('.membershipAlert').css("top", "-35px");
        $('.top-bar').css("top", "0px");
        $('header').css("top", "35px");
        $('.isSticky').css("top", "102px");
        $('.sticky-box').css("top", "102px");

      });
    }

  }

  function keepAlertClosed() {
    // trying to keep the alert from reappering and keep spacing correct
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    var membershipAlert = document.getElementById('membershipAlertWrapper');


    if (windowSize <= 950 && membershipAlert.css('display' === 'none')) {
      $('.top-bar').css("top", "-35px");
      $('header').css("top", "0px");
      $('#cd-lateral-nav').css("top", "0px");

    } else if (windowSize >= 950 && membershipAlert.css('display' === 'none')) {
      $('.top-bar').css("top", "0px");
      $('header').css("top", "35px");
      $('.isSticky').css("top", "102px");
      $('.sticky-box').css("top", "102px");
    }
  }

  function alertSystem() {
    slideNav();
    membershipClose();
    keepAlertClosed();
  }

  // execute on load
  alertSystem();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    alertSystem();
  });

});
```

I'm still new to JS development and using StackOverflow... Sorry if I've broken all the rules...

Comment: Most of the stuff, if not all, that your jQuery does, should be done using CSS and media queries.

Comment: then should I be using JS to add/remove CSS classes .onclick? to close the alert?

Comment: Look for [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) and read carefully... It will enlight you. ;)

Comment: To add/remove classes, look for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), whatever the event... And I foresee that you have the ability to dynamically create elements... So also look for [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Here's what you should do: place `.hasAlert` class on some common parent (probably `<body>`). Code in transitions and delays using CSS to animate each of the elements involved, for each responsiveness interval. Use a browser that allows you to toggle classes on/off on elements to adjust your CSS in the browser and copy-paste it in your stylesheet when you're happy with it. All that's left for your JavaScript is to toggle `.hasAlert` on `<body>`. Also note that without markup your JavaScript is not verifiable. We can't test it. Add in the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: Note you need to add a [mcve] in the question itself. Links to external examples will no longer be useful to other readers once they change. Being useful to future readers with a similar problem is the only reason you (or anyone else, for that matter) get help on [so]. So, the least you can do is make sure your question remains relevant over time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot of work to avoid hardcoding your styles from Javascript, and to use css instead. The use of window size can be done easily using the media selector. I am only here showing a snippet of [media selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to replace slideNav(); there could be some errors as I did not have a way to validate.

I did not reimplement the other functions, you can do the same. you will need to add an additional css class to the container of these elements, and then apply the required css for it.

```css
.membershipAlert {
  top: 0px;
}

.isSticky,
.sticky-box {
  top: 137px;
}

@media (max-width: 950px) {
  .top-bar {
    top: -35px;
  }
  
  .header {
    top: 35px;
  }
  
  .isSticky,
  .sticky-box {
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 950px) {
  .top-bar {
    top: 35px;
  }
  
  .header {
    top: 70px;
  }
  
  .isSticky,
  .sticky-box {
    position: sticky;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to toggle CSS classes with JS that way if the window resizes, the rules can be set with CSS. It still needs to be fine-tuned a bit but the functionality is there.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  header {
    top: 35px;
  }

  .membershipAlert-closed {
    top: -70px;
  }

  .header-alert-closed {
    top: 0px;
  }

  .top-bar-alert-closed {
    top: -35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
  .membershipAlert-closed {
    top: -70px;
  }

  .isSticky-alert-closed,
    .sticky-box-alert-closed {
  top: 102px;
  }

  .top-bar-alert-closed {
    top: 0px;
  }

  .header-alert-closed {
    top: 35px;
  }
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $top_bar = $(".top-bar"),
      $header = $('header'),
      $sticky_box = $('.sticky-box'), 
      $is_sticky = $('.isSticky'),
      $membershipAlert = $('.membershipAlert'),
      $membershipClose = $('.membershipClose');

  $membershipClose.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $membershipAlert.toggleClass('membershipAlert-closed');
    $header.toggleClass('header-alert-closed');
    $sticky_box.toggleClass('.sticky-box-alert-close');
    $is_sticky.toggleClass('isSticky-alert-closed');
    $top_bar.toggleClass('top-bar-alert-closed');
  });
});
```

Comment: Some comments that may help: **1)** I would have set the breakpoint like: `(max-width: 949px)` and `(min-width: 950px)`... or 950/951... **2)** When a class is defined the same in both @medias... like `membershipAlert-closed`, that means it could be outside the @media and apply in all case. **3)** There is a missing `d` on "closed" of the 3rd toggleClass.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. '.membershipClose' is applied to an X icon in the alert. I'll make changes to media q. And yes, you're right, .membership-closed can be placed outside of media q and in general CSS. Small oversight out of pure excitement. Cheers.